# What are the possible Android Element-Attributes for custom styles?

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin

I have the following code example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="GreenText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Does anyone knows where to find a list with all available "Attribute-Keys" for the name-attribute?

An example would be `android:###` for Padding, Text-Size and Margin

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes

Comment: @Quicklearner I got the code example from this site. But there is no list about the values I want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the list of all available attribute keys here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#lattrs